# Can Java.util.function accept 2 arguments?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm just trying to understand what is happening here ?
Is the java.util.function.Function concatenateTwoStrings accepting two arguments here ? Since, according to documentation it should accept only 1 argument or is there some under the covers conversion to BiFunction ?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Main {
    static Function<String, String> concatenateTwoStrings (Integer id){
        return str -> str.concat(id.toString());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Main.concatenateTwoStrings(12).apply("hello"));

    }
}
```

The code compiles and the output is "hello12"

Comment: It's accepting the `"Hello"` as the argument to your `Function<String, String>`, which takes a string and appends `id.toString()` to it. It isn't taking two arguments, you simply made a `Function` that is built off of a side effect / dynamically generated.

Comment: Thanks very much for explanation!so i suppose  a form of currying  is happening here ?

Comment: It’s not currying, as you have never defined a function with two arguments. You just used a value from the surrounding context. But you can do currying like `id -> str -> str.concat(id.toString())`. By the way, `str.concat(id.toString())` can be written as `str + id`

Answer (score 3):

No, `concatenateTwoStrings` is not accepting two arguments there. Furthermore, there is absolutely nothing in the code that you posted that in any way indicates that the function might be accepting two arguments, so it is unclear what gave you this impression and why you are asking the question.

So, you should have explained precisely what it is about the code that you posted that gave you this impression and made you ask this question.

To save you from the trouble, I bet that it is the `Function<String, String>` part that confused you.

Well, if you look at the definition of `Function<T,R>` you will see that the 1st generic parameter corresponds to the ***one and only one*** argument accepted by `apply()`, while the 2nd generic parameter corresponds to the ***return value*** of `apply()`.  So, `Function<T,R>` does not describe a void function with two parameters, it describes a function with one parameter and one return value.

Comment: the input argument being Integer for concatenateTwoStrings and the return value being Function<String,String>I assume. Thanks , I get it now.